# Dash becomes black after startup in Saucy

Tags: unity, unity-dash, 13.10

[image]
It also happens when I log out and log in.
It did not happen in Raring or Saucy beta 2.
I have Intel's integrated GPU and no additional drivers. Unity never behaved weird before in my computer.
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, as I believe it is related to issues with Intel iGPU drivers which ship with Ubuntu by default, as a number of other Intel users are having this same problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

This will add the oibaf PPA, switch the obaif PPA to Raring as it currently doesn't support Saucy yet, then upgrade all of your open source graphics drivers to the latest 'Updated and Optimized' open source graphics drivers.

Comment: Would I have to input the commands one by one or can I paste the whole thing together and press enter?

Comment: Paste the whole thing together. I hate posting one by one, so I always string everything together with ';'.

Comment: Ok, it has fixed the problem but now dash takes more than 30 seconds to appear and till then my computer is unresponsive.

Comment: Sounds like http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2045769 which still points to a graphics driver bug. Try rerunning `sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y` then reboot. I find it strange that you are experiencing this bug with an Intel iGPU though as they are supposed to be very well supported. Something else you can try is `sudo rm ~/.compiz ~/.config/compiz-1 -R` then reboot.

Comment: Also try `sudo aptitude upgrade -y; sudo aptitude dist-upgrade -y`

Comment: Still no improvement. I will try the 64bit version.

Comment: 64 bit also does not work. I have reported a bug in Launchpad. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1243016

Comment: May want to just stick with Ubuntu 13.04 for another month or two. I keep seeing people everywhere with graphics issues, and oibaf still has yet to properly support Saucy.

Comment: If you open the dash just after start-up or after changing the wallpaper it works okay. Maybe someone working on this bug may want to hear this. Does anyone know the relevant bug to this problem. I searched launchpad and couldn't find.

Comment: @PrabathSwarna https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1232726