# Update to saucy broke dash

Tags: unity, 13.10, unity-dash

I updated to Saucy this morning, and my computer freaked out mid-way through and I was forced to power it off to get it to respond.

When I restarted it (naturally) didn't work, so I launched a terminal and used apt to continue the install.  I wish i remembered what I executed...but I don't.

Now I have my desktop back and everything seems to be working except the Dash.  Super-key + typing now just shows me a spinner and nothing.

[image: My Dash. Doing nothing.]

I've deleted zeitgeist and software center caches, and I've tried to install `unity-place-applications`, but no effect, because I can't find it...and it doesn't feel like the sort of thing that would be in a separate ppa...:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unity-place-applications
[sudo] password for cpfohl: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unity-place-applications
```

Any ideas where I can start tracking this down?  All the apps are still there, I can launch them with the command line if I know where they are, but the dash just isn't doing anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1233029

Fixed with:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home
```

Similar to:

[Dash becomes black after startup in Saucy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362845/dash-becomes-black-after-startup-in-saucy?rq=1)

But I didn't show anything....And my dash was tan...because that's how I have it set up.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and that helped me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-scope-home
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work in my case (upgrading from 13.04).

I than try this other one:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-* unity-scope-home
```

and the unity-lens-* re-installation phase fix the problem.

(taken from here: http://adec.altervista.org/blog/ubuntu_13-10_upgrade_issues/)